# How to run a .NET Core 3.1 single-file app on MacOS?

Tags: .net, macos, .net-core, avaloniaui

I have an application in .NET Core 3.1.200 with this PublishProfile for targeting osx-x64:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=208121. 
-->
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <PublishProtocol>FileSystem</PublishProtocol>
    <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
    <Platform>Any CPU</Platform>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <PublishDir>bin\Release\netcoreapp3.1\publish\</PublishDir>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>osx-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <SelfContained>true</SelfContained>
    <PublishSingleFile>True</PublishSingleFile>
    <PublishReadyToRun>False</PublishReadyToRun>
    <PublishTrimmed>False</PublishTrimmed>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

I've run `dotnet publish myapp.cproj /p:PublishProfile=profile.xml` and at the end the /publish folder contains a single file "myapp" (this is correct since PublishSingleFile=True).

But it has no extension. How do I run it on MacOS?

**EDIT**: I've discovered I can simply run it from Terminal with `./myapp`. But how to run it by double-clicking on Finder? For now, it shows:

[image]

Comment: Long time Mac/Linux users know what are console applications and how to run them at a terminal, so you don't need to take any extra step. Double click in Finder should only trigger an application with user interface, which you should develop using a framework like Xamarin.Mac.

Comment: The application is actually a GUI app (made with [Avalonia](https://avaloniaui.net/)), and I'm not targeting long time Mac users but casuals. They expect to see the user-interface right after they double-click the icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET Core based applications (with user interface) must be packaged up as application bundle, so as to be recognized by Finder properly.

It is a lengthy process, but Avalonia guys wrote an article with detailed steps,

https://docs.avaloniaui.net/docs/distribution-publishing/macos

You can use `dotnet-bundle` tool to automate most of them.

Comment: Thanks! I will try it soon

Comment: Actually I had issues with dotnet-bundle, it does not seem to be maintained and it didn't produce the exptected results. Anyway I've solved by following the "manual" procedure (https://avaloniaui.net/docs/packing/macOS#manual)

Comment: [the link](https://avaloniaui.net/docs/packing/macOS) is dead.

Comment: @BedirYilmaz the guys switched to `docs.avaloniaui.net`.